# How to get the time of specific timezone using C#,?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nodatime

Good Day

I need to determine the time (DateTime object) in the Australian Western Standard Time regardless
what the user's local time zone is set time zone can be anything i will pass in log out date time and then when the user logs in he will get the log out time of his country standard time and not the server time

so how do i achieve this :) using offset

```
TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Convert.ToString("Australian Western Standard Time"));

  DateTime yourESTTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my time" is 2pm? Your question is *very* confusingly worded.

Comment: side note: `Convert.ToString("...` what's the purpose of converting a string to a string?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am sorry for the wordings but  (my time" is 2pm) my local Pc time

Comment: Right, but how is that relevant? Are you just interested in the current time in Australia?

Comment: @side Sorry for that i accidentally copied that .

Comment: The question is still not at all clear. Why do you want the Australian time zone at all? You should almost certainly be *storing* any value as UTC, and convert to the user's local time zone just for display purposes.

Comment: Just for example i am using Australian time zone. User will be storing his standard time belonging to his or her nation :)but when he logs in the system .I want to show his last log out date and time

Comment: I am storing the TimeZone.Id

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
DateTime australianTIme = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
    DateTime.UtcNow, "Australian Western Standard Time");
```

Comment: even Jon Skeet couldn't understand question yet and u answered..bravo :P

Comment: 1)Mid-Atlantic Standard Time

2)E. Europe Standard Time

3)Kamchatka Standard Time  It gives me error if i pass these string

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you just want to get the *current* time in a particular time zone, you can use:

```
// No need to call Convert.ToString - it's already a string!
string zoneId = "W. Australia Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
DateTime australianNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, zone);
```

You might want to consider using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`, by the way - you can always get a `DateTime` from that, but it means you have the offset if you ever need it.

You might also want to consider using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, which splits up "local time", "a point in time in a time zone" etc rather more clearly, IMO. You'd use:

```
// You'd normally inject this instead, so that you can use a fake clock for
// testing
IClock clock = SystemClock.Instance;

// Or you could use the TZDB provider, with the appropriate time zone ID
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl["Australian Western Standard Time"];

// What is the current time in the given time zone? The result retains the
// time zone as well as the instant in time, but properties like Hour return
// the *local* time in that time zone.
var zonedDateTime = clock.Now.InZone(zone);

// You may not need this at all - it depends on what you want to do
var localDateTime = zonedDateTime.LocalDateTime;
```

Comment: Thank you for applying how to get time using offset

Comment: @suraj: What do you mean? Please try really hard to be clear in what you're asking for.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations OVer here there are so many time zone as compared to the timezone in the windows registry

Comment: @suraj: Well those are abbreviations, where often you'll get two abbreviations for the same time zone. For example, the Pacific time zone uses PST and PDT. But if you use TZDB, you'll see a *lot* of time zones. It's still not clear what you're asking about though...

Comment: i will rewrite the question again my grammar is not so good

Comment: i have re-written my question  again

Comment: Thanks for sharing! May I ask you something about your first code snippet (the one incl. `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, zone);`)? Will this work at any given time no matter whether it's currently daylight saving time or not (daylight saving in both time zones and also just in one time zone as does happen temporarily because not all time zones switch to/from daylight saving time at the same time)?